# Need a Choice column in a custom list for selecting "Language"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, custom-list, language-pack

I have a custom list in SP2013 subsite and I need a choice column for selecting the language type i.e. English,French,Spanish etc and this selection of language should change the language that is to be entered for another column.

Any alternative apart from enabling the multi language settings in the top level site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for cascaded dropdowns?

Comment: Nope, radio buttons

Comment: So on selection of one radio button the second radio button should be automatically selected?